# Text inside a linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

I am having a linear layout in which I am having 2 text views. But there is some kind of padding between the text views'. How to remove the padding? I have attached a screenshot and source code below.

I don't need any space between 33% and completed.

Screenshot : https://www.dropbox.com/s/e69loke90q9c6nt/snip4.PNG

Code :

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toptext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="33%"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Completed"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Full Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/deckno"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Deck 1"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toptext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="33%"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Completed"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: show your detailed XML code here that will be easy to find error in your code

Comment: this alone is creating the problem

Comment: This may be because of the `layout_weight` given for the `TextView`. Show the full layout

Comment: @RKN  I have attached the full source.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy I have attached the full source code

Comment: It seems correct in my layout xml view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use Linear Layout. But i suggest you use Relative layout. Modify the below according to your needs

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toptext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="33%"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toptext" // place textview below toptext
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Completed"
    android:textSize="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Edit:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:padding="6dip">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/deckno"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Deck 1"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

 <RelativeLayout 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:paddingLeft="40dp"
 >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/toptext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="33%"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toptext"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Completed"
    android:textSize="10dp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: The above mentioned is exactly the one I require. But when I copied the code its not displaying anything.

Comment: @GeoPaul it works. That's the reason i posted a snap shot from the graphical preview

Comment: @GeoPaul check the edit. modify the same accordingly. Suggestion don't use hardcoded string's

Answer (score 0):

First remove this `android:layout_marginBottom="0"` this will not work. And then remove `android:layout_weight="1"` for both textviews keep in linearayout. TextView `layout_height` should be `wrap_content`. it will work check. textview size param `sp`

Answer (score -1):

change both widths to `wrap_content`
because currently each `TextView` takes half the screen width and aligns the text to it's center.

Answer (score -1):

From the information you gave, I think your problem is because you use `match_parent` for `layout_height` of your `TextView`s. By doing this you ask them to take all the height given by the `LinearLayout`.

Try `wrap_content`

Comment: I changed both to wrap_content but no differences.

Comment: @GeoPaul use relative layout

Comment: @GeoPaul : try remove `layout_weight`